# Поиск по фильтрам на PHP

Tags: php

Есть форма поиска с элементами выбора категории и города. При поиске текста все работает но при выборе одного из элементов списка категорий, ничего не происходит

Вот

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['submit_btn'])):?>
                    <?$category=$_GET['category'];
                    $city=$_GET['city'];
                    $result =$_GET['search'];
                   
                    $search=htmlspecialchars($result);
                    $sql= "SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE  `text`LIKE '%$search%' OR `title` LIKE '%$search%' OR `category_id`LIKE'%$category%' OR `city_id`LIKE'%$city%' ORDER BY `date` DESC  ";
                    $articles=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                   
                    while ($art=mysqli_fetch_assoc($articles)){?>
```

и результат там ничего интересного. Данные которые передаются через GET соответствуют данным из БД.основная проблема в моем Sql запросе.Если удалить

```
`text`LIKE '%$search%' OR `title` LIKE '%$search%'
```

то все работает и наоборот

Comment: если запрос по category_id ничего не находит, это значит что в БД нет ничего похожего на то что лежит в $category. Л - Логика

Comment: И советую почитать что-нибудь про SQL инъекции

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте запрос менять так

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE  `text`LIKE '%$search%' OR `title` LIKE '%$search%' AND`category_id`='$category' OR `city_id`='$city' ORDER BY `date` DESC  ";
```

Comment: НЕ получается.(